# Inserting an image in another person's question by edit

Tags: discussion, edits

Is it OK to add an image in another person's question?

Assuming it wouldn't change his question in any way, and that it would make more clear what he is asking.

---

For example [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692851/why-does-right-clicking-create-an-orange-dot-in-the-center-of-the-circle) the user describes his issue with words. An image (like the one in his link) would help viewers visualize the problem much faster and more accurately.

I don't mean copy pasting the image from an external site without permission. I mean creating a similar image myself which has no copyright restrictions.

(This is only mentioned as an example. There are posts where adding an image would have a much more profound effect.)

Comment: Are there situation in which it's appropriate, sure.  That said, I'd expect most situations where someone is trying to edit an image into another person's question to end up changing the question (whether they realize it or not).  Generally the main reason you'd edit an image into the question is because the OP posted a link, or provided it in a comment.  If you're generating an image that you feel somehow demonstrates what the OP is doing you *probably* want to post it as a comment, and let them throw it in the question if they feel i adequately represents their issue.

Comment: I usually will comment and let them know that an image would be helpful when appropriate. You could do a bunch of hard work making the image then the edit being rejected or it not actually being what the OP is getting/wants

Comment: @Servy Fair enough. What about cases like the one I linked above?

Comment: @user5061 If you wanted to pull the image in from the link, that'd likely be fine (as long as it's clear to the reader that the link is the source of the image).  Other than that, I'd stand by my and codeMagic's comments; probably not best to create an image and edit it in, as you might not be properly replicating all of the subtleties.

Comment: @Servy  Wouldn't I require permission from image owner to use it like that? If so, cant i circumvent that problem by generating it myself? (speaking about clear-cut questions)

Comment: I'm going with Yes.

Comment: @user5061 If you're properly citing it's source, it should fall under fair use.

Comment: @Will Hmmmm your image "slightly" deviates from my question intentions. It ll give the false impression I intend to edit other users'  questions drastically.

Comment: @user5061 thus my rollback.

Comment: @user5061 Oh, and since your edit would be only suggestions for now, please make it clear in the comment box that the images are representative of the OP's wishes (by providing a link or something).

Comment: @Servy Ok. Then my question has been answered in the comments. If someone can pack them up and post an answer, I ll accept it.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Well, if there is a change my edit will get declined in clear-cut cases where author didn't give his consent, then it's not worth doing it as an edit. It would waste time (of many people). Instead I would post it as comment.

Comment: That's the thing about updating someone's content--you have to accept the fact someone might roll it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Servy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298260/inserting-an-image-in-another-persons-question-by-edit#comment214868_298260)

> Are there situation[s] in which it's appropriate, sure. That said, I'd
>   expect most situations where someone is trying to edit an image into
>   another person's question to end up changing the question (whether
>   they realize it or not). Generally the main reason you'd edit an image
>   into the question is because the OP posted a link, or provided it in a
>   comment.
>
> If you're properly citing it's source, it should fall under fair use.
>
> If you're generating an image that you feel somehow
>   demonstrates what the OP is doing you probably want to post it as a
>   comment, and let them throw it in the question if they feel i
>   adequately represents their issue.

[ryanyuyu](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4320665/ryanyuyu)

> And since your edit would be only suggestions for now, please make it
>   clear in the comment box that the images are representative of the
>   OP's wishes (by providing a link or something)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't. I don't really see any fundamental difference between adding a new image and adding a new paragraph of text, which is very much frowned upon here.

I suggest mentioning it in a comment to the answerer.